# Is it possible to have an adjustable line in highcharts stack area graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have the below chart which is fine, however I have to add values to have the top line in place. It is a constant value and will never changes, How can I make this purple line permanent and also adjustable by the user?

[image: High Charts]

Solution:

```
plotLines: [{
                        color: '#FF0000',
                        width: 2,
                        value: 5.5,
                        dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                        id: 'plotline-1'
                    }],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is a [plotLine](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines). You can have it set to some default value on load and then remove/add when the user changes the value that they want to display. Lots of ways to do this.

Comment: Just what I was after. THanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set two xAxis and linked purple series to one, but rest of series (area) to other.

Examples of multiple axis http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes